# Prolog- Travel path and time

Tags: prolog

With the given data we need to find travel path and time.

```
byCar(auckland,Hamilton,103).
byCar(hamilton,raglan,42).
```

---

This will give me the path

```
    go(X,Y):- byCar(X,Y).
    travel(X,Y):- go(X,Y).
    travel(X,Y):- go(X,Z), travel(Z,Y).
    travel(X,Y,go(X,Y)):- go(X,Y).
    travel(X,Y,go(X,Z,Path)):- go(X,Z), travel(Z,Y,Path).
```

---

should I include time as a third function and increment it as T=t+t

```
go(X,Y):-byCar(X,Y,t).
travel(X,Y,T):- go(X,Y),
travel(X,Y,T):- go(X,Z), travel(Z,Y), T is t+t.
```

### This still does not give me the time.

My sample run :

```
 ?. travel(auckland,raglan,Y).
    Y = go(auckland, hamilton, go(hamilton, raglan))
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` is a constant in Prolog, since it starts with a lowercase, that means that queries like `byCar(X, Y, t).` will fail, unless it uses `t` as time in the facts, but that is not very likely.

You should use unification to unify the time with a variable, for example:

```
go(X, Y, T):-
    byCar(X, Y, T).

travel(X, X, 0).
travel(X, Y, T) :-
    go(X, Z, T1),
    travel(Z, Y, T2),
    T is T1 + T2.
```

or with an accumulator:

```
go(X, Y, T):-
    byCar(X, Y, T).

travel(X, Y, T) :-
    travel(X, Y, 0, T).

travel(X, X, T, T).
travel(X, Y, T1, T4) :-
    go(X, Z, T2),
    T3 is T1 + T2,
    travel(Z, Y, T3, T4).
```

Note that in the facts, you should write `hamilton` with a *lowercase*, otherwise it is a *variable*, which means that the fact `byCar(auckland,Hamilton,103).` says that `auckland` is connected with *all* cities, and each time takes 103 time units:

```
byCar(auckland, hamilton, 103).
byCar(hamilton, raglan, 42).
```