# Writing predicates in prolog, data search

Tags: prolog, logic, predicate, swish

Write the predicate, reach(Departure, Arrivals) to find all points you can get into from the Departure point.

We have this facts:

```
trip(Id, From, To, Price)       
Id — flight number
From — departure point
To — Point of arrival
Price — price  


                                                                                                                                                                

trip(01, kuiv, odessa, 1500).
trip(02, kuiv, lviv, 700).
trip(03, uzhorod, krum, 6000).
trip(04, vunohradiv, odessa, 2540).
trip(05, ternopil, kuiv, 3800).
trip(06, zaporizhya, donetsk, 900).
trip(07, ternopil, mariupol, 7500).
```

For example
?- reach(kuiv([odessa, lviv])).

kuiv - we enter
odessa, lviv - this is the result

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542448/prolog-travel-path-and-time and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprolog%5D+travel

Answer (score 0):

reach(Departure, Arrivals):-
trip(_, From, To, _)

I only know that this is how you need to start, maybe someone more knowledgeable will help you